# Opencart how to visible all categories we have?

Tags: opencart

i want to need all the categories we have visible in some way, are there any possible extension that could be used?

website does here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn

Comment: Why dont you write your own code?

Comment: If you are willing to but it, I can write it's code for you.

Comment: Please help me for writing a code...

Comment: Are you familiar with coding?

Comment: Yes i can do if you provide me some solution.

Comment: @AliZia : i dispaly category list but how to mange its title like movie/ video or more .

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: @AliZia : dear please can you give me your code..?

Comment: add me on skype. My id is syed_ali_zia

Comment: @ViralM Why you do not use header controller code to get all categories and sub category in your requirement. I think it will use to show all the categories as per your requirement. Give me whote if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a category then make all products children of it by changing the parent value in data tab of the categories. Make sure you make it visible by checking 'top'